# how to get script of existing schema in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql5.6 workbench. I have a schema and many tables in this schema. Now I need to get the complete schema on my other system for which I need the script.
I created all the tables without running the script so I don't have script. But now I want to generate the script from the workbench so that I can run it on another system.

please suggest me how I can get this script from mysql workbench 5.2CE.

Also please help me to get it out in a .sql file format script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Right click on the schema
2. Select "Send to SQL Editor"
3. Select "Create statement"

If you want to generate a complete create script (i.e. including the tables), select the schema AND all the tables (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to multiselect), then follow steps 1 through 3.

Comment: i want the whole script of al tables so please suggest me hopw to get the scripts of all tables

Comment: @NavKumar Ok, then you will have to select all the tables in the schema and select before doing step 2 and 3

Answer (score 1):

Select the File, Export, Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script menu item to start the Forward Engineer SQL

[Get more details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-sql-scripts.html)